# Expect script waiting for timeout when there is long output

Tags: expect

I would like to have expect run a command, display it's output and exit.

This works:

```
time expect -c 'spawn date; expect eof'
spawn date
pátek, 21. dubna 2017 23:43:24 CEST

real    0m0,060s
user    0m0,010s
sys     0m0,022s
```

This also works, the file contents is seen immediatelly but there is timeout of 10 seconds before expect exits:

```
$ time expect -c 'spawn cat /home/vmarek/.vimrc; expect eof
...
real    0m10,086s
user    0m0,012s
sys     0m0,024s
```

My .vimrc is ~ 22kB

Thank you

Comment: how long would it take if you run `cat /home/vmarek/.vimrc` manually? which version of Expect are you using? you can also try `expect -d -c 'spawn ...'` and see what's happening.

Comment: I can't reprocude problem. Try this `expect -c 'spawn cat .vimrc; expect -re .+ exp_continue eof'`

Comment: That didn't help too. At the moment I filed a bug against expect on Solaris and we'll see where this goes. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out. It's a bug in Solaris or in expect shipped with Solaris. I can not reproduce on Linux too. I never used expect before so I assumed that it's a problem on my side. Thanks everyone who took the time to look at this.

Vlad